# word to make someone feel bad or insulted

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word that can correctly interpret a situation like this

You boss constantly insults you, make you feel like you know nothing or if you are some idiot may be, has no empathy for your feelings, basically insults you around verbally and even in front of others, is bossing around and ordering things like "Go to your pc, find this and come back to me right now", "I am saying, do it right now" etc.

What is the correct word for this situation. I am looking for more than one word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one possible interpretation, the situation represents  *[harassment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/harassment#Noun)* (“Persistent attacks and criticism causing worry and distress”).  Under other interpretations, some of the following verbs may apply.
• *[intimidate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intimidate#Verb)*, “To make timid or fearful; to inspire or affect with fear; to deter, as by threats; to dishearten; to abash”
• *[chivvy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chivvy#Verb)*, “To subject to harassment or verbal abuse; To coerce, as by persistent request”
• *[tyrannize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tyrannize#Verb)*, “to oppress someone; to rule as a tyrant”
• *[browbeat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/browbeat#Verb)*, “To bully in an intimidating, bossy, or supercilious way”
• *[bully](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bully#Verb)*, “ To intimidate (someone) as a bully; To act aggressively towards”
• *[micromanage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/micromanage#Verb)*, “To manage, direct, or control a person, group, or system to an unnecessary level of detail or precision.”
• *[enslave](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enslave#Verb)*, “To make subservient; to strip one of freedom; enthrall”
• *[domineer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domineer#Verb)*, “To rule over or control arbitrarily or arrogantly; to tyrannize”
• *[dominate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dominate#Verb)*, “To exert an overwhelming guiding influence over something or someone”

Comment: I think I was looking for the world "harassment"